# Integrate Wikitute to Ionic2 mobile app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, wikitude

I want integrate wikitude to my existing ionic2 application. I saw there is a cordova plugin for wikitude integration.
But there is no example for ionic2 in wikitude documentation.

Is there any boilerplate code for wikitude with ionic2 ?
How to start integration wikitude with ionic2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download sample boilerplate code from [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/ionic-marketplace/wikitude-ionic-2-starter-app/147583467166600/wikitude-ionic-2-starter-app.zip).

For the start intergration of wikitude with ionic2

1. Add Plugin

   ionic plugin add https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-cordova-plugin.git
2. Register, and download a key for the Wikitude SDK
3. Add key to  src/app/app.component.ts

   WikitudePlugin._sdkKey = "YOUR-SDK-KEY"

Answer (score 0):

There is an awesome seed project for that here

https://market.ionic.io/starters/wikitude-ionic-2-starter-app

and here

https://github.com/pbreuss/wikitude-ionic-2-starter-app